# can't log-in in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

- I have a problem regarding logging in my wordpress site.
- When i try to login the there is no error but does not redirect/load the page.
- Is this a problem with my Hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Try url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit.php
```

Where `www.mydomain.com` is your site's address.